# Service lifetime problem

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service, lifetime

I currently have a thread that spawns and either pulls the next command off a queue and executes it or sleep for a bit and try again. However I do not want it to run if there are no more commands in the queue and there are no more activities alive in the application.

My question is what route should I investigate, and which routes might have other people taken?

1. Refactoring the service to only handle commands as they come in, and not spawning a thread
2. having a third condition in my thread (if !activityCount = 0 stop thread)

Or, do I have it wrong and android can terminate my thread automagically if there are no more activities bound to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to create a service that is stopped "automagically": see the [Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html) page in the Dev Guide:

> A bound service typically lives only
>   while it serves another application
>   component and does not run in the
>   background indefinitely.

Comment: haha, thanks. I will look at this article I must have missed it. I am binding my activity but the point is I want the application to finish io to the servers even if a user is moving on to other applications.